# Error Message not working for PHP user check

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and have wrote a register PHP page, it is working fine and can add to database for new users. But when adding repeated username, the error message does not appear. did i miss out any codes or do i need to change the codes?

My Code:

```
<?php

define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'login');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());


function NewUser()
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password =  $_POST['password']; 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, surname) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$firstname', '$surname')";


$data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
if($data)
{
echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED, YOU CAN SIGN IN NOW";
}
}

function SignUp()
{
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
{
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());

if(!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error()))
{
    newuser();
}
else
{
    echo "SORRY, YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER.";
}
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SignUp();
}
?>
```

Comment: `$row` is undefined. If anything, you'd want to use `mysql_num_rows()` to check if a row of the same exists.

Comment: Plus, you're open to some serious SQL injection and for so many reasons.

Comment: `!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query)` doesn't do what you think it does

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new, you might as well ditch the `MySQL_` statements and go with something more secure like `MySQLi_` or PDO. This won't disallow you to use databases, they are just more secure.

Also: `$row` is undefined.

And once again, because you are new, I suggest using an editor that gives you indentation to your code. Indentation makes your code more readable, and helps other people help you when you have problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

`$row` is undefined and try using `mysql_num_rows` 
when ever you want to access the column values you can use `mysql_fetch_array`
here in this case you just checking for `$query` returned a row or not.
so you can change you code to

as you did it for 
   `$data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
    if($data)
    {
      echo "YOUR REGISTRATION IS COMPLETED, YOU CAN SIGN IN NOW";
    }`

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$_POST[username]' AND password = '$_POST[password]'") or die(mysql_error());`

`if($query){
     newuser();
}else{
     echo "SORRY, YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER.";
}`

Comment: which part of the code are u referring to for //your code here